# VBA to format the displayed date within a directory name

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have prepared a code whereby various cells are read to determine the name of files within a Directory where the and source can be found. The file that is then opened is dependant on the date specified in cell S2 of the Active Sheet, which is in the format "mm.dd.yy".

The code seems to read most cells fine, but when it comes to the date it is reverting it to "dd\mm\yyyy" and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

The research I've done says that clearly distinguishing between cell content and display format is very important and I thought that's what I was doing with the NumberFormat, but it doesn't seem to have worked.

This is the code I'm using;

```
Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
ws1.Range("S2").NumberFormat = ("mm.dd.yy")

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "Q:\Accounts Department\DF Period End ADI\Security Plus Reconciliation\Historical Data\2015 - 2016\P" & ws1.Range("S3").Value & "\Securiy Plus Data\W" & ws1.Range("S4").Value & "\FileName " & ws1.Range("S2") & ".xls"
```

Any help is, as always, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `ws1.Range("S2")` to `Format(ws1.Range("S2"), "mm.dd.yy")`

Comment: Also spot on, hadn't thought to do it this way. It's still all a learning curve! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Use **.Text**:

```
Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
ws1.Range("S2").NumberFormat = ("mm.dd.yy")

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "Q:\Accounts Department\DF Period End ADI\Security Plus Reconciliation\Historical Data\2015 - 2016\P" & ws1.Range("S3").Value & "\Securiy Plus Data\W" & ws1.Range("S4").Value & "\GO NORTH EAST " & ws1.Range("S2").Text & ".xls"
```